# Who are these Multiverse Flashes?

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification, the-flash

*The Flash* #52 (2018) opens with the panel below (minor spoilers for the *Flash War* arc). This "council of Flashes" seems to feature the Flashes of different universes.

[image: Council of Flashes]

And a different angle right after, revealing even more Flashes.

[image: Different angle]

Who are all these Flashes?

Comment: I self-answered some of those below, because I genuinely , but there are still some that I can't quite identify: red and blue Flash from second image, for instance, or the blonde one behind Danica. I wonder if they were drawn at random, or if they are actual characters? The Mercury Flash intrigues me too...

Comment: Wasn't the multiverse collapsed down to one in *Crisis*? Oh well, I guess it was a Comic Book Death!  ¶  Can't we assume that any otherwise unidentifiable alt-Flashes were invented for the occasion?

Answer (score 10):

### Overview

First, let's look at an overview image of the two comic strip pages, with labels, just to appreciate how much there is to identify.  Then we'll go through each section of the images in detail.

[image: (overview of first page)]

[image: (overview of second page)]

### Details of first image

#### First, the Flashes that appear in real big, seen from the back.

[image: (detail)]

- 0k: Johnny Quick from Earth 3? Goggles and goblin-shaped head don't match, but the hinged shoulders and general look is reminiscent of the guy.

[image: Johnny Quick]

- 0l: Speed Freak of Earth 47, from *Animal Man* #23 (1990). Spiky hair, yellow costume with diagonal red pattern, red lightning bolts "ears". Same as 4p.

[image: Speed Freak]

- 0m: Flash of Earth 42, from *The Multiversity* #2 (2015)? Same as 4o, but from back here.

[image: Earth 42]

- 0n: Lia Nelson of Earth 9, from *Tangent Comics: The Flash* (1997). Blondie, purple outfit with a cape and a spikey symbol on the chest. Same as 4j, 4n.

[image: Lia Nelson]

- 0o:
- 0p: same as 4l, but profile view.

#### Next, the four characters at the center of the podium:

[image: (detail)]

- 0q: Fastback, the reptilian rocket, of Earth 26, from *Captain Carrot and his amazing Zoo Crew!* #1 (1983) - thanks to RDFozz for pinpointing an earlier depiction of that one! Same as 6a, 7c

[image: Fastback]

- 0r: The Accelerated Man of Earth 19, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Headscarf, goggles, white face mask, yellow gloves. Same as 6z, 7b

[image: Earth 19]

- 0s: Wally West from the original Justice Riders Else world.  Same as 6c, 7a.  Identified by [user112667](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/112667/user112667).
- 0t: Barry Allen of Prime Earth, the current main continuity. Same as 6b, 7d.

#### First three bottom panels

[image: (detail)]

- 4a:
- 4b: Flash of Earth 22, from *Kingdom come* (1995). All red, blurry, a lightning bolt around him, helmet. Same as 2k.

[image: Kingdom come]

- 4c: Accelerator of Earth 39,  from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Grey costume, right-pointing orange arrow. Same as 6u, and possibly 1c.

[image: Earth 39]

- 4d:
- 4e:
- 4f: Same as 1a?
- 4g: Danica Williams of Earth 12, from *Batman Beyond Unlimited* (2010). Yellow-tainted goggles, spiky black hair, yellow lighting bolt on black disk, yellow wristbands, black gloves. Same as 1b.

[image: Danica Williams]

- 4h:
- 4i: Bizarro Flash of Earth 29, from *All Star Superman* (2007). Same "chain" pattern around the lightning bolt symbol, electricity coming out of his ears, yellow gloves. Same as 1f, 6w.

[image: Bizarro Flash]

#### Last three bottom panels

[image: (detail)]

- 4j: Lia Nelson of Earth 9, from *Tangent Comics: The Flash* (1997). Blondie, purple outfit with a cape and a spikey symbol on the chest. Same as 0n, 4n.

[image: Lia Nelson]

- 4k:
- 4l: There is a Mercury Flash (6x, 1g), but they don't look the same that at all...
- 4m:
- 4n: Lia Nelson (see 4j, 0n)
- 4o: Flash of Earth 42, from *The Multiversity* #2 (2015)? We only saw Steel, Batman and Wonder Woman from this Earth, but it's the same child-looking, chibi-style art... Same as 0m.

[image: Earth 42]

- 4p:

#### Let's take a detailed look at the bottom left podium on the big panel

[image: (detail)]

There are some characters here that appear as just part of an outline with no details, and are probably impossible to identify (but if you can identify them, do add the answer).  These get the labels 5a–m, which don't appear in the overview image.

- 0e:
- 0f:
- 0g:
- 0h:
- 0i:
- 0j:
- 1a: Same as 4f?
- 1b: Danica Williams of Earth 12, from *Batman Beyond Unlimited* (2010), same as 4g.
- 1c: Accelerator of Earth 39; see 4c, 6u.
- 1d:
- 1e:
- 1f: Probably Bizarro Flash of Earth 29, from *All Star Superman* (2007), same as 4i, 6w.
- 1g: Mercury Flash of Earth 44, the same as 6x.
- 1h:
- 1i: Red Racer of Earth 36, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Same as 6y.

[image: Earth 36]

#### Now the few characters on the top left

[image: (detail)]

- 0a: Blitzen of Earth 10, from *The Multiversity: Mastermen* (2015)? Nazi-looking helmet fits, but not the blue pants or the "ruffed" boots and gloves...

[image: Blitzen]

- 0b: Unnamed Flash of Earth 30, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Suit is red on the front, black on the back, kneepads, yellow boots with straps, yellow gloves, bike-like helmet

[image: Earth 30]

- 0c:
- 0d:

#### The left part of the bottom podium on the top right

[image: (detail)]

- 2a:
- 2b:
- 2c:
- 2d:
- 2e:
- 2f:
- 2g:
- 2h:
- 2i:
- 2j:

#### The right part of the bottom podium on the top right

[image: (detail)]

- 2k: Flash of Earth 22, from *Kingdom come* (1995). Same as 4b.
- 2l:
- 2m:
- 2n: Jace, the Flash of the Planet Petrus, post 2754 A.D, which appeared in Speed Force #1, 1997. His father was the Flash before him & he saved his son (Jace) from dying from a disease by trying to take him in to the speed force, but failed. The Speedforce took him instead & passed his speed on to Jace. It's the fathers costume, but it appears to be on Jace (who is blonde, while his father wasn't).
- 2o:
- 2p:
- 2q:
- 2r: Aquaflash of Earth 32, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015).  No explanation needed. *Scales!*

[image: Earth 32]

- 2s:
- 2t:
- 2u: Blood Flash of Earth 43, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015)?  The picture's pretty blurry but this guy's mouth seems odd. Earth 43 is populated by vampires, including a vampire Flash

[image: Blood League]

- 2v: Mary Maxwell of Earth 6, from *Just Imagine Stan Lee with Kevin Maguire creating the Flash* (2001). White suit, knee pads, ribbon-like headdress

[image: Mary Maxwell]

- 2w: this purple/white costume is a bit reminiscent of Marvel's speedster Quicksilver in the 2018 *Quicksilver: No Surrender* series ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM1xI.jpg))
- 2x:
- 2y:

#### Finally the top podium on the top right

[image: (detail)]

- 3a:
- 3b:
- 3c: This costume is reminiscent of Robin's old one back in the 50s-60s?
- 3d:
- 3e:
- 3f:
- 3g:
- 3h:
- 3i:
- 3j:
- 3k:
- 3l:

### Details of the second image

#### Foreground of top panel

[image: (detail)]

- 6a: Fastback, the reptilian rocket, of Earth 26 (1983). Same as 0q, 7c
- 6b: Barry Allen of Prime Earth. Same as 7d, 0t.
- 6c: Wally West from the original Justice Riders Else world.  Same as 0s, 7a.
- 6z: The Accelerated Man of Earth 19, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Headscarf, goggles, white face mask, yellow gloves. Same as 0r, 7b.

#### Then the bottom panel

[image: (detail)]

- 7a: Wally West from the original Justice Riders Else world.  Same as 0s, 6c.
- 7b: The Accelerated Man of Earth 19, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Headscarf, goggles, white face mask, yellow gloves. Same as 0r, 6z
- 7c:  Fastback, the reptilian rocket, of Earth 26 (1983). Same as 0q, 6b.
- 7d: Barry Allen of Prime Earth. Same as 6b, 0t.

#### The podiums in the background of the top panel

[image: (detail)]

Again we can see a lot of bare outlines in the back of the crowd that I haven't yet labeled, but if you can identify any, please mention it.

- 6d:
- 6e:
- 6f:
- 6g:
- 6h:
- 6r:
- 6s:
- 6t:
- 6u: Accelerator of Earth 39,  from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Same as 4c, possibly 1c.
- 6v:
- 6w: Bizarro Flash of Earth 29, from *All Star Superman* (2007). Same as 4i, 1f.
- 6x: Mercury Flash of Earth 44, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Elongated face, backwards-rotated yellow lightning bolt on white disk. Same as 1g.

[image: Earth 44]

- 6y: Red Racer of Earth 36, from *The Multiversity Guidebook* (2015). Same as 1i.

Comment: Note that Fastback first appeared in *New Teen Titans* #16 (technically; it was a preview), then in *Captain Carrot and His Amazing Zoo Crew* #1.

Comment: @RDFozz indeed for _Captain Carrot_, will edit that in right away! As for the preview, I don't have access to it but the are two (main) _New Teen Titans_ series if I'm not mistaken; are you talking about the 1980 or the 1984 one?

Comment: You're right, should have specified. the preview was in the 1980 series #16.

Comment: Also, Pre-Crisis, he was from Earth-C. Of particular note, mostly because when they "cross over" with the JLA (Just'a Lotta Animals), they're from Earth-C-Minus. I miss Captain Carrot (the New-52 version in *Threshold* just wasn't the same thing. At all. Really).